# Jquery hide and show function not working correctly

Tags: jquery, slideshow

On My eg here http://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/cYrqY/15/ the show and hide doesn't work correctly, when I'm closing doesn't stop.
any idea why? 
is the best way to do this? or I can do it in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extra `.slideUp` at the beginning of the `click` handler, see here http://jsfiddle.net/cYrqY/17/

Comment: @DD77 - I thought I had put up a link to the fixed version, it's good now.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this by doing the following:

```
$(this).click(function () {
    $('.toggleDiv').is(":visible") ? $(this).text(options.hideText) : $(this).text(options.showText);
    $('.toggleDiv').slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a toggle, why not use .toggle()?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.show_hide').toggle(
       function(){$('.toggleDiv').fadeIn(1000);},
       function(){$('.toggleDiv').fadeOut(1000);}
        );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cYrqY/19/